I cannot insert a React icon dynamically in a cell-table
I try to insert a React Icon in a cell (table), but I get the message

Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'

My code is very simple:
const iconCell = row.insertCell(4);

const iconDiv = document.createElement('div');

iconDiv.appendChild("<FontAwesomeIcon icon={RiDeleteBin6Line}/>");
iconCell.appendChild(iconDiv);


Any reason you're using DOM methods and not rendering the <FontAwesomeIcon />` component in your JSX?

It looks like you should go through some React basics first.

You are right. Now I am learning React Tables. I thought that I could do it with normal tables.

I should use a normal icon instead of a React Icon, for example:
document.querySelectorAll('#cell-i').forEach((cell)=> {
         i++; 
         cell.innerHTML = '<img src="'+ i + '.png">'; 
    });

